# break one text with several documents within in arrays

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pdf

I have a challenging mission involving regex. At least I think is challenging.

I have the following string (text) being pulled from a PDF: http://www.regexr.com/3c5ei

This is a text generated by a software every month to companies. The problem is that it has companies that produce those documents in mass, so there is PDFS with 100 of these texts, for example.

The text layout is always the same, what changes is information such as date, name, numbers, values, etc.

I'm trying to get a PDF file that has 500 documents of that (500 texts with the same mask/layout with the same value) and break into several arrays, an matriz for each document. Understand?

For example, if I have two documents into a PDF of this, I want to turn in two matriz.

To be able to do this, I need a very complex regex, and then that you enter, awesome guys.

I've been able to remove the PDF text, I am now trying to create the correct pattern to pull these texts.

For example, in the following scenario: I have two documents in this text: http://www.regexr.com/3c5el

They are equal,

beginning is: `MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO`
the end is: `Z6: 0`

However as I said earlier, it is not always the same beginning and the same end.

I managed to find a standard which is:

Right at the beginning of the text, the following sentence: `RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP`
At the end, before beginning another text, the following sentence: `RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP`

The file map would be:

```
INFORMATION HERE FILE 1
RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
FILE INFORMATION HERE 2
RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
```

I'd like your help to be able to capture that text and break in the number of correct documents.

I was able to create the following regex, but is not very good:

```
^(.*?RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP.*?RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP.*?(RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP)|.*?)
```

But is not working very good... this is to much complex for my knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right at the beginning of the text, the following sentence: `RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP` At the end, before beginning another text, the following sentence: `RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP`

Match everything in between with `[\s\S]*?` as that will also match newlines. And use the `/g` modifier to get all matches.

**Regex**

```
/RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP([\s\S]*?)RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP/g
```

**Code**

```js
var regex = /RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP([\s\S]*?)RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP/g
var text = `
INFORMATION HERE FILE 1
RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 1
FILE INFORMATION HERE 2
RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
RESUMO DAS INFORMAÇÕES À PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP
OTHER INFORMATION FILE 2
`;
var m;
var num = 0;
 
while ((m = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    num++;
    document.write("<h3>Match " + num + "</h3><pre>" + m[1] + "</pre>");
}
```

Comment: its almost this, but i need get the information before the RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP.. (INFORMATION HERE FILE 1).. i need get all this texts -> http://www.regexr.com/3c5ei

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/3c5fv its more like this, but until the end, and break in the Z6: 0 (without use the z6: 0 because this data is relative)

Comment: You can't expect a regex to magically know where it starts or ends. You need to find a specific anchor or pattern to use in your regex. By the way, there are no newlines in your text?

Comment: i find other pattern extending your regex, thanks very much!!

Comment: Perhaps you should match it before stripping newlines. Also, if this comes from an HTML page, I'd use an DOM parser on the raw HTML.

Comment: i create this pattern http://www.regexr.com/3c5g2 and is exactly what i need, this information won't change never.. but... should match 6 times, not just one.. do you know why?

Comment: The `^.*` at the beggining would only match at the start of text. [just remove it](http://regexr.com/3c5g5)